# HTML5 Drag and Drop dataTransfer setData not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, drag-and-drop

For some reason the following drag and drop code works in Chrome and Safari but not in Firefox. I've made my example as simple as possible to narrow down the possible issues but I haven't been able to narrow it down. I would appreciate any suggestions.

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/shervinkayvon/pen/JjdrKWN)

```
event.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', '<span>Hello world</span>');
```